# In table how to get the table TD tag data when clicking?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I am loading some card details on each of the `td` tag in table. When I click on particular `td` data, the action is not working. I already wrote the jQuery function for `onclick` event of `td` tag, but it not working.

Table:

```
<table class="metricTable" border="2" bordercolor="white" style="background-color:#066B12;">
  <tr>
    <td class="metrics" onmouseover="this.bgColor=&#39;#4DBD33&#39;;">
    <input type="hidden" value="matches" /> 
    <input class="card_value" type="hidden" value="" />
    <div class="card_content1" align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:150%;font-weight: bold;"></div>
    <div class="card_content" align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF;font-weight: bold;"></div></td>
    <td class="metrics" onmouseover="this.bgColor=&#39;#4DBD33&#39;;">
      <input type="hidden" value="runs" />
      <input class="card_value" type="hidden" value="" />
      <div class="card_content1" align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:150%;font-weight: bold;"></div>
      <div class="card_content" align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF;font-weight: bold;"></div>
    </td>
    <td class="metrics" onmouseover="this.bgColor=&#39;#4DBD33&#39;;">
      <input type="hidden" value="centuries" />
      <input class="card_value" type="hidden" value="" />
      <div class="card_content1" align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:150%;font-weight: bold;"></div>
      <div class="card_content" align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF;font-weight: bold;"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="metrics" onmouseover="this.bgColor=&#39;#4DBD33&#39;;">
    <input type="hidden" value="fifties" /> 
    <input class="card_value" type="hidden" value="" />
    <div class="card_content1" align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:150%;font-weight: bold;"></div>
    <div class="card_content" align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF;font-weight: bold;"></div></td>
    <td class="metrics" onmouseover="this.bgColor=&#39;#4DBD33&#39;;">
    <input type="hidden" value="batting_average" /> 
    <input class="card_value" type="hidden" value="" />
    <div class="card_content1" align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:150%;font-weight: bold;"></div>
    <div class="card_content" align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF;font-weight: bold;"></div></td>
    <td class="metrics" onmouseover="this.bgColor=&#39;#4DBD33&#39;;">
      <input type="hidden" value="wickets" />
      <input class="card_value" type="hidden" value="" />
      <div class="card_content1" align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:150%;font-weight: bold;"></div>
      <div class="card_content" align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF;font-weight: bold;"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="metrics" onmouseover="this.bgColor=&#39;#4DBD33&#39;;">
    <input type="hidden" value="bowling_average" /> 
    <input class="card_value" type="hidden" value="" />
    <div class="card_content1" align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:150%;font-weight: bold;"></div>
    <div class="card_content" align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF;font-weight: bold;"></div></td>
    <td class="metrics" onmouseover="this.bgColor=&#39;#4DBD33&#39;;">
    <input type="hidden" value="best_bowling" />
    <input type="hidden" value="" /> 
    <input class="card_value" type="hidden" value="" />
    <div class="card_content1" align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:150%;font-weight: bold;"></div>
    <div class="card_content" align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF;font-weight: bold;"></div></td>
    <td class="metrics" onmouseover="this.bgColor=&#39;#4DBD33&#39;;">
      <input type="hidden" value="catches" />
      <input class="card_value" type="hidden" value="" />
      <div class="card_content1" align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:150%;font-weight: bold;"></div>
      <div class="card_content" align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF;font-weight: bold;"></div>
    </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

jQuery function for `onclick` on `td`:

```
$('.metricTable td').click(function(){
    alert("hi");
    //some code
});
```

When I click on td, simple alert also not coming.

**Can anybody provide the code for onclicking the td data and how to retrieve the particular td data.**?

Please reply.

Comment: Is the table having the id metricTable?

Answer (score 1):

please try this

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {

     $('.metricTable tr > td').click(function(){
                       alert($(this).html());
                                  //some code
                    });
});
```

Demo here :http://jsfiddle.net/MCeJ9/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try this if the value you looking for is in the input tag:

```
$('.metricTable td').click(function(){
    var input1 = $(this).find('input').eq(0).val();
    var input2 = $(this).find('.card_value').val();
    alert(input1+" and "+input2);
});
```

for the value in div tag

```
$('.metricTable td').click(function(){
    var input1 = $(this).find('.card_content1').text();
    var input2 = $(this).find('.card_content').text();
    alert(input1+" and "+input2);
});
```

Comment: Where did you get `input` or `.card_value` from? :/

Comment: he posted the html a while ago, the structure is
<td >                                
<input>
<input>
<div></div>
<div></div>                        
</td>

Comment: if the value that you want is in the div tag, I will edit it.

Answer (score 0):

If the cells are dynamically generated, you need to use the `.on()` function:

```
$('.metricTable').on('click', 'td', function(){
    alert("hi");
    //some code
});
```

To get the contents of the cell, use the `.text()` or `.html()` functions:

```
$('.metricTable').on('click', 'td', function(){
    alert( $(this).text() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wish we could see your markup ... and we could tell whether or not the whole table is dynamically generated! It it is and markup looks like that below:

```
<table class="metricTable"> . .. . .. . . . .</table>
```

Then try delegated approach:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on( 'click', '.metricTable td', function() {
        alert( $(this).html() );
    });
});
```

When putting the data in the table thus:

```
$(this).find('.selector').val( card[0][4] );
```

At the same time the source data 0,4 can be stored in the same element thus:

```
$(this).find('.selector').data('source','0,4');
```

These can be retrieved respectively as follows:

```
   theValue = $(this).find('.selector').val();
   theSource = $(this).find('.selector').data('source');
```

Comment: Great!! Guess you're adding the whole table dynamically!

Comment: hi i have one problem how to get this value please, intially i loaded the cards to table by this way, the user card is var           userCard =JSON.parse(localStorage['user_Card']); is taken from loacal storgae. and it loaded to table by this way $(this).find('.card_value').val(userCard[0][4]); i want to get this value(userCard[0][4]) for compare purpose, how to get this value.. please reply

Comment: alert( $(this).find('.card_value').val() ); should give you back the values. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: hi i have one problem how to get this value please, intially i loaded the cards to table by this way, the user card is var           userCard =JSON.parse(localStorage['user_Card']); is taken from loacal storgae. and it loaded to table by this way $(this).find('.card_value').val(userCard[0][4]); i want to get this (userCard[0][4]) for compare purpose, how to get this value.. please reply

Comment: @user3433253 I just did above **$(this).find('.card_value').val()** ... did you miss it?

Comment: hi in alert i getting the value of that , but i want the which parameter we passed initially to val method means, i want this one userCard[0][4] as an output, not userCard[0][4] value,because i want to compare the metrics of clicked value,opposite card